# pre processing of image before k-means in matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, k-means

I am getting the problem in implementing K-means that, how to arrange the first parameter to kmeans, assume this is the kmeans..

```
[cidx center] = kmeans(F, 3, 'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',5);
```

How to get F in proper format,
if size(F)==[d,n], where 'd'` is a set of data points each of n-variables. How, to get such an F?

What are these 'd' (data points) and 'n' (variables).

How a normal Grey Scale image can be converted to this format.

And for output **center** is a 3*n matrix (3 is number of clusters, and 'n' is number of variables). How is the result related to variable, what are there variables?

I am able to understand first output **cidx**, the cluster indices of each data point (each data point, belong to which cluster 1st or 2nd or 3rd,  am i right?)

Help me regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not the size of F, but the type. kmeans needs a double there. Try this line, it works on my MATLAB

```
[cidx center] = kmeans(double(F), 3, 'distance','sqEuclidean','Replicates',5);
```

Comment: I have refined my problem. Can you help me with the question again?